# TCP Server and chating between two clients in java

Tags: java

I want to make a simple TCP client-server program that accepts request from multiple  clients and start a two way chat between two clients i such a way that one client can send multiple messages to other without waiting for the response of other client.
I have written some code and could not know what to do next

```
//Server Side code 
public class ServerThread extends Thread 
{
    private StringProperty clientname;
    private StringProperty clientIP;
    private IntegerProperty  clientport;
    private Socket clientsock;
    File file;
public ServerThread(Socket cs,String name)
{
    clientname=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    setClientsock(cs);
    clientIP=new SimpleStringProperty( cs.getInetAddress().getHostAddress().toString());
    clientport=new SimpleIntegerProperty(cs.getPort()); 
    this.start();
}

public void run()
{   
    System.out.println("Now i am started:");
    try 
    {
        System.out.println("clientname.getValue()  "+clientname.getValue());
        BufferedReader infromclient = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( clientsock.getInputStream() ));        
        file=new File(clientname.getValue()+".txt");
        if(!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();
        while(true)
        {  
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
            writer.write((char)infromclient.read());
            writer.close();

        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public StringProperty getClientname() 
{
    return clientname;
}
public void setClientname(String name) 
{
    clientname=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
}
public StringProperty getClientIP()
{
    return clientIP;
}
public void setClientIP(String string) 
{
    this.clientIP.set(string);
}
public IntegerProperty getClientport() 
{
    return clientport;
}
public void setClientport(int clientport) 
{
    this.clientport.set( clientport );
}
public Socket getClientsock() 
{
    return clientsock;
}
public void setClientsock(Socket clientsock) 
{
    this.clientsock = clientsock;
}

}
```

client side code

```
public class Cleint {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        Socket clientsock=new Socket("127.0.0.1",5055);
        System.out.println("Conected with server:");
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ));
        BufferedReader infromServer=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( clientsock.getInputStream() ));
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(clientsock.getOutputStream(),true);

        String fromServer = infromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server says: " + fromServer);
        String string=in.readLine();
        out.println(string);
        while(true)
        {   System.out.print("Enter Msg:");
            string=in.readLine();
           // javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Client Enter value");
            out.println(string);
        //  System.out.println("In client loop");
            fromServer = infromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server says: " + fromServer);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Thanks @ UnholySheep i found the solution by @Raja Hammad Farooq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-Client-Server-chat-application.
This may help you.

https://github.com/aboullaite/Multi-Client-Server-chat-application/blob/master/javaSwing-Server_Client/src/aboullaite/ChatClient.java

Comment: While the links may have good solutions to the problem, it's better to explain the solution and attach a link to explain more